# Scrapy MySQL: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

When I run my code I get the following error.

> 2019-10-22 09:14:24 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: BooksSpider.close of >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/mx/python-virtual-environments/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site->packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 204, in execute
>      query = query % args
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/home/mx/python-virtual-environments/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site->packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
>      result = f(*args, **kw)
>    File "/home/mx/python-virtual-environments/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site->packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
>      return receiver(*arguments, **named)
>    File "/home/mx/Desktop/books_crawler/books_crawler/spiders/books_SQL.py", line 79, in close
>      cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(title, description, rating, upc, >availability)" "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", row)
>    File "/home/mx/python-virtual-environments/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site->packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
>      raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
>   MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

I tried reformatting the '%s' numerous ways but don't know what I am doing wrong.

**This is a snippet of my code:**
>

> csv_data = csv.reader(open(csv_file))
>
> ```
>    row_count = 0
>    for row in csv_data:
>        if row_count != 0:
>            cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(title, description, rating, upc, >availability) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", row)
>        row_count += 1
>
>    mydb.commit()
>    cursor.close()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

checking mysql [website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html), parameters are not enclosed in single quotes. might want to try this. I also removed the greater `>` symbol on your availability column.

```
row_count = 0
   for row in csv_data:
       if row_count != 0:
           cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(title, description, rating, upc, availability) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", row)
       row_count += 1

   mydb.commit()
   cursor.close()
```

Comment: Hello Metal, the greater symbol was accidentally added when I tried to add the code block here on Stackoverflow. I ran your query statement, but I still get the same error message.   **File "/home/mx/python-virtual-environments/scrapy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting**